# Page served locally cannot find assets in parent folders of root

Tags: javascript, html, css, localhost

I'm using a local webserver to serve a simple, static html page. The project has the following folder structure:

```
/site
  /build
    index.html
  /bower_components
```

Index.html is accessible on `http://localhost:5455/`. In index.html I am loading some assets from `../bower_components`:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/normalize.css/normalize.css">`
`<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`

But neither firefox or chrome seem to be able to load resources from this parent folder. I get the following error:

**Cannot GET /bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js**

So it looks like it isn't looking in the parent `../bower_components`, but in `build/bower_components`, which obviously isn't right. Why is this, is it some sort of security protocol? And how can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server is mapped to the `build` folder, you will NEVER be able to access parent folders, for obvious security reasons!
Some solutions are:

**1 - Map your server root to the**  `site` **folder**

or

**2 - Put the**  `bower_components` **folder inside the**  `build`  **folder**

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Solution 1 works for me. It's unfortunate that the root of the dev site (which is now `localhost/build`) cannot be the same as the root of the dist version (the dist build task will move all the scripts inside the root), but at least it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You did bind the /build folder to the root of the web server.
You have to bind the /bower_components to some sort of web served address before attempting to reference it in HTML.